# Image align right does not work in joomla 1.5

Tags: html, joomla

I'm trying to align right an image in joomla.
In previous page it works OK.
But in next page that property does not work.
In editor it shows OK, but in browser image is not aligned to the right.

I tried to put an image into div, did not work.

Link: http://awtosatlyk.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=1&Itemid=2&limitstart=5

Comment: It looks like you are just beginning to develop the website. Do yourself a favor and use a recent version of Joomla. What editor are you using and why are you using a deeply nested table layout?

Comment: 1.5 is past end of life and has known security issues. You should be on 3.1.5 for a new site.

Answer (score 0):

add width="90%" to table class="blog"like this:

```
<table width="90%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="blog">
```

Hope this will help you..